# Is there an equivalent NTILE function in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to divide my collection into n groups with equal number of rows. Is there an equivalent to SQL's NTILE function in MongoDB?

I'd like to create a MongoDB view for my collections that will add an additional column (partition_no)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. You'd better add detailed code snippets to get attention from others. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use $bucket or $bucketAuto  using $aggregation you can ahchieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. The [$bucketAuto](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucketAuto/) aggregation stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            '$bucketAuto': {
                "groupBy": "$_id",
                "buckets": n
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

This returns the structure of:

```
{ _id: { min: minIdOfBucket, max: maxIdOfBucket }, count: number }[]
```